# LaTex - Exact math

Tags: macros

I am quite new to LaTex and I am wondering if it's possible to use exact math in LaTex. I.e. I want to feed the script some input, which may be either a number or a variable, and it should perform some calculations on it (e.g. multiply/divide) and print the exact solution.

Consider this .tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mass{30}
\newcommand\acc{9.8}

\newcommand\force{\the\numexpr \mass * \acc \relax} % F=m*a

\begin{document}
  \section{Exerted force}
    F = \force N
\end{document}
```

This prints `F = 270.8N` when `mass = 30` and `acc = 9.8`. Can this script, however, be modified in order that changing `acc` to a variable like `g` instead of a number will print `F = 30g`?

EDIT:
I should not have used the words 'exact math' as they are misleading as to my intentions. I have rephrased the question and it's posted here: [LaTex - perform algebraic operations on variables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475490/latex-perform-algebraic-operations-on-variables)

Comment: I'd suggest a different interface to accommodate for the changes. Something like `\force*` that would print `30g` if `\mass` is known and otherwise (`\force`) printing the result of the product `\mass * \acc`. Alternatively, construct something like a key-value interface: `\force{mass = 30, acc = g}`. Then you can condition on the respective symbols. Would that work for you?

Comment: If you want *exact* math, you should consider [SageTeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex) and [pythontex](https://ctan.org/pkg/pythontex)

Comment: @Werner thanks, but I don't think that'd cover all of my needs. For example, when adding two forces 1g and 2g + π I want the result to be 3g + π. I think that'd be hard to do that way.

Comment: @DG' thanks. I didn't even know it was possible to include python code. I'll look into this.

Comment: @kotek: Sure. And why don't you just type this in manually? Is it really that difficult that you'd need to calculate the *algebraic* evaluation automatically?

Comment: @Werner because the force is used in a lot of other equations throughout the document and I want to be able to easily change the force (albeit a variable or a number). It would save me a lot of time if I would not need to do this by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are high-level packages for this, `siunitx` and `xfp`. The latter provides `\fpeval` for math expressions with a fairly natural notation.

The former provides bells and whistles for formatting numbers and units.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,xfp}

\newcommand\mass{30}
\newcommand\acc{9.8}

\newcommand\force{\fpeval{\mass * \acc}}

\begin{document}

$F = \SI{\force}{N}$

$F = \SI[scientific-notation=fixed,fixed-exponent=2]{\force}{N}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...and how would this answer/evaluate the [requested *algebraic* evaluation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475377/latex-exact-math#comment1199812_475377)? As in `1g + 2g + \pi = 3g + pi`?

Comment: @Werner That's a joke, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: @egreg No, it is not. I would like the `acc` to also be able to be equal to a variable like `g` and then perform some basic algebra on it (add 4g to it, for example), but I would not know if that would be possible. I now see I have misphrased my question, so I'll accept this answer and I'll ask a new question that clarifies my intentions.

Comment: @kotek While it is theoretically possible to implement a CAS in TeX, I don't think anybody has the time and patience to do it, even if just simple symbolic computations are required.

Comment: @egreg actually, there are LaTeX packages for python and sage that make it possible. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/475490/181768 if you are interested.