# LaTex - perform algebraic operations on variables

Tags: macros, variable

Suppose I've got the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mass{30}
\newcommand\acc{9.8}

\newcommand\force{\the\numexpr \mass * \acc \relax} % F=m*a

\begin{document}
  \section{Exerted force}
    F = \force N
\end{document}
```

It creates three 'variables': `mass`, `acc` and `force`, which is the product of the first two.

This specific example (`mass = 30`, `acc = 9.8`) prints `F = 270.8N`, as is intended.

The multiplication is performed by the `\numexpr` command. This works whenever `mass` and `acc` are both regular numbers. If the `mass` or `acc` is a variable (i.e. `\newcommand\mass{m}`) the document fails to build, as `\numexpr` can only perform operations on numbers.

Is there a way to perform algebraic operations on variables, such that when `mass = 30g` and `acc = g`, it will print `F = 30g^2`? I know this does not make sense physically, but I think the point is clear.

A few other examples:

- `mass = m`, `acc = 9.8` -> `F = m*9.8` or `F = 9.8*m`
- `mass = m`, `acc = g` -> `F = m*g` or `F = g*m`
- `mass = x`, `acc = x` -> `F = x^2`

EDIT:
As @PhelypeOleinik kindly pointed out, `\numexpr` only works on *integers*. So while 9.8 * 30 = 294, it gives 270.8 as result, because 30 * 9 = 270 and it appends the .8.

Comment: you shouldn't use LaTeX here.

Comment: You should note, however, that `30×9.8` is `294`, not `270.8`. You get `270.8` because `\numexpr` does integer multiplication and `30*9` is `270` and the `.8` is appended to the result. If you did `\newcommand\acc{9.banana}` you'd get `270.banana` (and no error :). Use `\dimexpr` for “real” (real in a variable type context) variables.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik oops, didn't know that! I should have bothered to verify the results.

Comment: @kotek Have a look at the [LaTeX3 interfaces](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf). There are several programming goodies implemented there. The one that might interest you most is **Part XXII The `l3fp` package**. That one provides an excellent floating point interface to LaTeX. It doesn't have a symbolic calculation module, like what you're asking, but with the tools provided one may be able to implement something (given enough time and patience :).

Comment: The `sagetex` package can do this. See the accepted answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460400/is-there-a-math-package-with-a-set-of-macros-that-would-help-manipulate-terms-in/460401#460401). The package gives you access to a computer algebra system and Python programming. Documentation on `sagetex` is [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex). Not part of distribution, best access is through free [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) account. Sage documentation [here](http://www.sagemath.org/)

Comment: @DJP Thanks. That might be even better than my solution using `pythontex` and `sympy`. Consider posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code using the `sagetex` package that you requested:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
m = 30.0
a = 9.8
Force = m*a
var('g')
mass = 30*g
\end{sagesilent}
\section{Exerted force}
    F = $\sage{Force.n(digits=5)}$ N \\\\
If the mass is $\sage{mass}$ then it's square is $\sage{mass^2}$.
\begin{sagesilent}
var('m')
acc = 9.8
\end{sagesilent}

$F = \sage{m*acc.n(digits=2)}$\\
\begin{sagesilent}
var('a')
m=a
\end{sagesilent}
If the mass, $m$, is equal to the acceleration, $a$ then 
$F = \sage{m*a}$.

Sage even works with square roots:
\begin{sagesilent}
var('g')
m=sqrt(3)
\end{sagesilent}
$F = \sage{m*g}$ which, if you want decimals, is about     $F=\sage{m.n(digits=4)*g}$
\end{document}
```

The output, running in Cocalc (mentioned in my comment above), is:
[image]

In Sage, x is a variable by default. Any other variables have to be defined as done in the code, for example var('g'). The `sagesilent` environment is like scratch paper. It is made up of the Python and Sage commands that will do the calculations. Use the format `\sage{}` to get the result. Since it's numerical, it's done in math mode (between dollar signs). Sage will tend to give lots of digits. The `.n(digits=5)` will force the answer to be 5 significant figures.

Comment: Thank you! Clear explanation and it does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `pythontex` package to embed python in your LaTeX document and then use the python `sympy` package for symbolic computation like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{pycode}
```

```python
from sympy import *

m = sqrt(3)
a = symbols('g')
f = m * a
```

```latex
\end{pycode}

\begin{document}
  \section{Exerted force}
    F = $\pyc{print(latex(f))}$
\end{document}
```

This requires that you have installed LaTeX, python3, the `pythontex` package for LaTeX and the `sympy` package for python. Also, some knowledge of python doesn't hurt.

Short explanation of the code:

`\usepackage{pythontex}` imports the required package.

`\begin{pycode}` begins a block of python code.

Let's look at the following block of python code:

```python
from sympy import *

m = sqrt(3)
a = symbols('g')
f = m * a
```

This imports the `sympy` library, sets `m` equal to the square root of 3 and `a` to a variable `g`. It then multiplies `m` and `a` and stores the result in `f`. Note that the `sqrt()` function used to take the square root of 3 is a function from the `sympy` library and not from the math library. This means that `m` is *exactly* equal to `sqrt(3)` and is not an approximation.

`$\pyc{latex(f)}$` then prints whatever `latex(f)` returns. The value of f is now equal to `sqrt(3) * g`. By passing it through the `latex()` function it gets printed using LaTeX notation, so the dollar signs are necessary to enter math mode.

This can be built by first calling `latex`, then `pythontex` and then `latex` again.

In the end the document will look like this:

[image: Result]

Some resources on `sympy` and `pythontex`:

- https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/intro.html
- https://tug.org/tug2013/slides/Mertz-A_Gentle_Introduction_to_PythonTeX.pdf